# NS_AVAILABLE(10_10, 8_0) causing crash when building for iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I developed an application and released it for iOS 7 last year and all was good. I updated the app for iOS 8 recently and released the update with the development target still set to iOS 7. Now I've been getting emails that the app was crashing for iOS 7 users but working fine for iOS 8 users. After debugging I found that what was causing the crash was the following property I had defined on an NSOperation subclass -

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *name;
```

The crash I'm getting is "unrecognized selector sent to instance".

In iOS 8, Apple had added the following property to NSOperation -

```
@property (copy) NSString *name NS_AVAILABLE(10_10, 8_0);
```

So why does this cause the application to crash on iOS 7 when I've defined the property on the subclass? And also, how can I avoid this happening in the future as Xcode doesn't give me any warning?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the problem. You are building your app with a Base SDK of iOS 8. So your class's `name` property doesn't do anything because the compiler sees that the subclass (`NSOperation`) already has a property named `name`. In other words, when built with a Base SDK of iOS 8, the compiler does not synthesize the setter and getter in your subclass because it is redundant with the `NSOperation`.

But when the app is run under iOS 7, `NSOperation` (and your subclass) do not have this `name` property so you get the runtime error trying to use the non-existent getter or setter methods for the property.

The best solution is to rename your property. Then your class's property will be generated and used.